# Why does supplemental mapbox geocoder allow for only one search?

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

Mapbox GL JS has a module that lets you insert supplemental data in the form of a geojson to search against.

I have set up my data to work with mapbox and take advantage of this search feature.

However, after i search for one individual park, the geocoder seems to get disabled and wont let me search for another geojson data point. I CAN search for a feature in the geocoder, such as a city, state etc, but the geocoder does not allow for two back to back searched of data in the geojson.

I do not know what to try to fix this

The example can be found on their website, which exhibits the same flaw as i get in my code

https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/forward-geocode-custom-data/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a bug. Suggest you report it at https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder/issues

Comment: Indeed, I've filed https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder/issues/281

Comment: A quick fix might be to downgrade to an older version, since I think this bug was introduced after localGeocoder.

Comment: thanks for submitting the bug Andrew, really appreciate it. as a next step, how can I downgrade my version of the Mapbox GL JS Geocoder?